# Does KSQL support Kafka stream Processing Guarantees?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I wonder if KSQL support https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#processing-guarantees

Exactly_once semantic ?

Answer (score 1):

> **KSQL** is implemented on Kafka Streams API which means it **provides
>   exactly once delivery guarantee**, linear scalability, fault tolerance
>   and can run as a library without requiring a separate cluster.

It is stated in Confluent's [KSQL: Streaming SQL Engine for Apache Kafka](https://openproceedings.org/2019/conf/edbt/EDBT19_paper_329.pdf). See last sentence of the abstract.

Comment: If it does how come enabling exactly_once does not solve the problem exposed in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895856/ksql-table-table-left-outer-join-emit-same-join-result-more-than-once/57899873#57899873